# How to resolve repeated emails asking for verification of my Apple ID?

Tags: windows, apple-id, internet-explorer

I have received my email to verify my Apple ID, but when I click on the verify now it will not open a verification window in Internet Explorer 8.  I receive the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

I do not know what else to do.  I can log into my Apple ID and resend the verification email over and over, but I continue to receive this message.

Comment: Try again with a different web browser. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: kiamlaluno: No, he isn't. He said he's using Internet Explorer 8, which is Windows-only.

Comment: This is off-topic and probably belongs over at Super User.  But Nathan is right -- you'll want to try the web page in a different browser.  It could also be that your email client broke the link somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem where internet explorer doesn't open certain web pages. It may be an issue with internet explorer not having SSL enabled. In internet explorer go to the Tools menu and click internet options (you can also get to internet options from control panel). Click on the advanced tab and scroll to security, make sure there are check marks where it says SSL 2.0 and 3.0 and then click apply.

If that doesn't work just install another browser like safari or firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything special about visiting https://appleid.apple.com than any other web site that uses SSL.

Check the date on your computer, turn off extensions, allow cookies - you generally get a message that your account has been disabled if that's the issue - so unless your browser suppresses that message, it's likely a browser configuration issue.

Going to another computer to make sure your account hasn't been locked due to too many attempts might be prudent if you're confident your browser isn't somehow blocking the web site from doing it's job.

http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/ really does walk you through the things to check.